# Invalid Integer "NaN" for array of items cant access

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, frontend, stripe-payments

The price is an array of length 3, since it is array I can't access the specific item's price how to fix this any help? the error is Invalid Integer "NaN"

```
line_items: req.body.map((item,price)=> {
                const img = item.image.asset._ref;
                console.log(img)
                const newImage = img.replace(
                    "image-",
                    "https://cdn.sanity.io/images/xxxxxxx/production/"
                )
                .replace('-jpg', '.jpg');

                return{
                    price_data: {
                        currency: 'usd',
                        product_data: {
                            name: item.name,
                            images: [newImage],
                        },
                        unit_amount: item.price[price]*100
                    },
                    adjustable_quantity: {
                        enabled: false,
                    },
                    quantity: item.quantity,
                }
            }),
            success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/success`,
            cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/cart`
        };
```

Comment: From what I understand, item.price should be something like [1,0,0] and when you parse, it should be 100 * 100, but you only use item.price once